# If the options for my likert variable are described with percentages, can I treat it as continuous?

Tags: regression, logistic, likert, ordered-logit, interval-censoring

I am conducting research on production quality improvement in a group of different companies. The main question is:  "How has product quality changed?" The answer is on a 6 point Likert scale:

- Deteriorated
- 0-5% improved
- 5-10% improved
- 10-20% improved
- 20-30% improved
- More than 30% improved

Can I use the percentage information as well to treat my DV as continuous or I should treat it as only ordinal? Also how can I use grouping of companies' data to improve my analysis?

Comment: I don't think so because your data is categorical and you don't know the exact percentage your respondent give.

Comment: Say, a respondent gives 10-20%, how do you know it's 11%, 10%, or 15%?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "improve my analysis"? What do you want to do? Do you want to do a regression? Do you want to do a goodness-of-fit test? What are you looking for? What's your sample size? etc

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to a numerical variable? In SPSS, you could do it. But it would only convert it to a list of encoding values (0 for Deteriorated, 1 for 0-5% etc).

Comment: I think you should consider the possibility that the answer may be "neither". If you consider that a person could give an actual percentage, then the selected range they give will be an [interval censored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_%28statistics%29#Types) observation. I've taken the liberty of adding the corresponding tag.

Comment: (ctd) ... I think that's probably the best way to use the information you have. [You *could* assign scores to categories but you'd need additional data for it to be more than a guess, & the 2 end categories would be problematic. If you treat as ordinal, you lose information]

Comment: @Glen_b My interpretation from you is that, the answer is no unless there is more data to sufficiently justify the conversion?

Comment: Well, unless you're prepared to rely on the reasonableness of some assumed scoring. The advantage of dealing with the interval-censoring is you use all the information that is there without imposing some additional, possibly dubious information. (That said, some reasonable set of scores may work fairly well in practice.)